# AJAX ComboBox Control

Tags: asp.net-ajax, controls, telerik

Can anyone suggest an AJAX ComboBox control that will allow the dropdown to suggest items where the string typed in appears anywhere in the string not just at the beginning.  Most of the controls I have found only search at the beginning.  Infragistics is supposed to work by searching anywhere, but the performance is poor, and I haven't gotten any help from their tech support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted several vendors.  Telerik responded quickly and their radComboBox met my needs.  They had good documentation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using ExtJs and overriding the "onTypeAhead" method of the combo.

There is a well supported community on their forums and you can always ping me if you want some help with that.

Comment: here's the demo of their combo control http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/combos.html